# Converting exec()-based Python code to iPython API

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I'm working on a personal project that involves something like a clone of Jupyter's Notebook. Right now, I have a `Cell` class that stores the user's code input and executes that code when it's told to. Each `Cell` executes in its own thread through the use of Python's `exec()` function.

I'd like to replace this functionality by implementing iPython's cell structure for a few reasons, primarily because it's hard/impossible to kill a Thread from within a Python script, so I can't interrupt the code execution without killing the main thread.

However, iPython's API doesn't seem to have any sort of integration for cells, execution, interruption, or any of the other features that the Jupyter UI provides. Where would I begin if I wanted to start converting my program to use iPython's API instead of my janky method?

Here's the abridged code:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
from networkx import algorithmse


class Cell:

    def __init__(self,
                 name_,
                 content_type_="python",
                 content_=" ",
                 top_=10,
                 left_=10):
        """
        :param name_: The cell's name
        :param content_type_: The type of content in the cell (markdown or python)
        :param content_: The contents of the cell, either markdown or python code
        :param top_: Cell's top position for the frontend
        :param left_: Cell's left position for the frontend
        """
        self.name = name_
        self.content_type = content_type_
        self.content = content_
        self.output = ""

        self.top = top_
        self.left = left_

    def execute(self):
        # Execute this cell's content

        if not self.content_type == "python":
            return

        global exec_vars
        ex_vars_copy = exec_vars.copy()

        try:
            print("<" + self.name + ">")
            exec(self.content, ex_vars_copy)
        except Exception as exception:
            print("Exception occurred in cell " + self.name)
            print(exception)

        exec_vars.update(ex_vars_copy)


class Graph:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Contains Cell objects and traverses them for execution."""
        # Networkx Directed graph
        self.graph = nx.DiGraph()
        self.parent = parent
        # Dict to keep track of cell names vs networkx node names
        self.names_to_indeces = {}
        # Dictionaries for variables created by cells
        global exec_vars
        exec_vars = {}
        # TextIO object
        self.ti = TextIO()

        self.executing = False

    def bfs_traversal_execute(self):
        import time
        if len(self.get_all_cells_edges()[0]) == 0:
            return

        self.executing = True

        root_cell = self.get_cell("", 0)

        root = threading.Thread(target=root_cell.execute)

        std_file_out = root_cell.name

        root.start()
        root.join()

        std_file_out += root_cell.output

        n_ = self.graph.neighbors(0)
        neighbors = [n for n in n_]

        while neighbors:
            new_neighbors = []
            processes = []
            for n in neighbors:
                neighbor_cell = self.get_cell(self.get_lookup_table()[n].strip())

                neighbor = threading.Thread(target=neighbor_cell.execute)

                neighbor.start()
                processes.append(neighbor)

                new_neighbors.extend([i for i in self.graph.neighbors(n)])

            for proc in processes:
                proc.join()

            for n in neighbors:
                time.sleep(.05)
                neighbor = self.get_cell(self.get_lookup_table()[n])
                std_file_out += "<" + neighbor.name + ">\n"
                std_file_out += neighbor.output

            neighbors = new_neighbors

        self.executing = False
```

[Code link](https://github.com/CharlesAverill/satyrn/blob/master/satyrn_python/interpreter.py)

Comment: Very cool!  I am doing something very very similar, though I'm using cytoscape for my graph editing.  Check it out, it is very awesome.  I've mostly just been executing everything fresh (no stay resident kernel), but now tackling something more iPythonish.  The iPython API is really poorly documented sadly.   I'm grubbing around for example usages right now

Answer (score 0):

I gave this some thought.  I think the iPython API seems a bit bloated and not particularly well designed - at least for my use case (similar to yours).   Implementing a simple messaging queue accessible to external processes is fairly trivial and you can just execute code off of that via a number of different pythonic approaches.

There are also quite a few auxiliary python libs that can simulate some of the completion/formatting that can be done in Jupyter.

ie, I think your janky method is perfectly fine.

In terms of threading, I am using asyncio / coroutines so interruption is fairly natural and simple to do.  In general, threads make less sense in python as they have poor parallelism and waste time locking and releasing the GIL.

If I need multicore access I generally always go multiprocess, but that's out of scope for this q/a.

Comment: This answer doesn't assess the problem I stated at all. I need to convert to iPython no matter what, `exec()` isn't working out.

Comment: Hmm, how is not working?  I find it works very well, though I use import/reload for my usecase as I save code to files first.  I use changeStream / mongodb to listen for async tasks to execute.  

I did a search on github, other than jupyter I don't really see anyone else using the iPython api, which wasn't surprising.  I think it's more of an internal API for jupyter at this point.  There is also prompt-toolkit,  bpython, mypython, ptpython, xonsh